# Extruder calibrated, but prints still oversized by .1 mm or so

Tags: calibration, extrusion, fdm, simplify3d

I've got a pretty straightforward problem. In general my printer is very accurate for the XYZ movements. What I'm running into is no matter what size my print is, the XY dimensions will be thicker by around .1 mm. And it's not just the external walls, but interior walls as well.

I have run single and double wall calibration prints to check my extrusion multiplier and they all check out correctly. I know that there is an XY compensation option in Simplify 3D, but I don't like it because quite frequently it results in a drastically different slice.

I know that cooling can cause a part to contract and distort, but this seems to be something different. It's very uniform all around. Is there another way to address this during slicing instead of the XY compensation? I definitely don't want to make the adjustments in my models because that results in a bunch of annoying math I don't want to get into.

Comment: So are you saying when you run the single and double wall tests, the wall thickness turn out fine. But when you print an actual part the walls are off by .1mm?

Comment: Yes. My walls are printing the expected width when doing the single and double wall tests. It's when I start having infill that the problem shows up.

Comment: You could try turning down the infill overlap setting to see if this helps

Comment: What infill density and what infill/perimeter overlap percentage are you using?

Comment: What extrusion multiplier you use?

Comment: @Davo - infill % doesn’t seem to effect it but typically 15%. 20% overlap. Trish - I’m using .96 for a multiplier. That’s both the default for my printer in S3D, and the number I get when calibrating my extruder.